# Equivalent of Fieldnames function for cells

Tags: matlab, cells, field-names

As the title says, just wondering if there is a function that works as fieldnames (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html) does, but for cells.

So if I have something like:

```
a = imread('redsquare.bmp');
b = imread('bluesquare.bmp');
c = imread('yellowsquare.bmp');
d = imread('greysquare.bmp');

e = {a, b, c, d};
```

I'm trying to retrieve either: a, b, c, d OR the image name without the extension.

I have tried `fn = fileparts(e)` and `fntemp = cell2struct(e,2)`, but I can't get it working.

Hope this makes sense
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cell array does not include any meta-information, like field name or file name.  If you want access to that information you'll need to change your data storage structure.  Some options include:

**Scalar Structure**
Good for when there is a single name to reference.

```
images.red = imread('redsquare.bmp');
images.blue = imread('bluesquare.bmp');
```

Use `fieldnames(images)` to get the names.

**Array of structures**
A little bit more general.  Allows completely general names (including special characters and spaces) and additional metadata if you need it (like "size", "author")

```
images(1).name = 'red';
images(1).im   = imread('redsquare.bmp');
images(2).name = 'blue';
images(3).im   = imread('bluesquare.bmp');
```

Use `{fieldnames.name}` to get just the names.

**Containers.map**
Probably more than you need here, but good to know about.  `help comtainers.map` for more.

Comment: Perfect, the Scalar structure is ideal for what I want to do. Thank you very much!