# Programmatically get valid switch/case values

Tags: matlab

When MATLAB scans through cases in a `switch/case` block, does it remember the values that it skips, and is it possible to access that list? I have a few functions with long `switch\case` block and I would like to have them return a list of valid case values if they make it down to `otherwise`. For instance, I have a function that returns a set of optical constants for a material.  It currently has about 20 different materials and it is growing as I consider new ones.

I realize I can brute-force it and just re-type all of the valid cases into a cell array under `otherwise` and have the function throw an error and return the list of valid responses, but maintaining both lists without errors or laziness creeping in over time is challenging.

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44203-getcases-list-of-all-cases-in-a-switch) interesting :)

Comment: Very nice! I see you ultimately went with a version of @mohsennosratina's method of horror :). One comment, though. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this code would not work if you were to highlight a section of code and hit F9 or execute a code section with Shift+Enter if you had not saved the file before doing so.

Comment: That is indeed true; it *must* be run from a file. I couldn't see how to do it any other way without placing requirements on how you should code a `switch`...Perhaps some day I know how to get rid of this dependency :) When I do, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: After receiving charming comments on my first solution, I propose another which needs more editing in your code than the first one but still less than other solutions so far (moved the original one to the end):

Let's define a function that grabs the values and keeps them in a persistent variable

```
function list = cc(value)
persistent allCases
if isempty(allCases) || (nargin == 0 && nargout == 0)
    allCases = {};
end
if nargin == 1,
    allCases = [allCases value]; 
    list = value;
end
if nargin == 0 && nargout == 1,
    list = allCases;
end
end
```

Now you can just add a `cc;` before `switch` to reset the persistent variable and pass all values in `case` statements to the function and call the function in the `otherwise` part to read the values:

```
a = 'a';
v = 'c';

cc;
switch a
    case cc({'b' v 1.2})
        %Multiple cases 
    case cc(2)
        %number
    case cc(ones(2))
        %matrix
    otherwise
        disp('Allowed cases are:');
        cellfun(@disp, cc);
end
```

This prints out:

```
Allowed cases are:
b
c
    1.2000
     2
     1     1
     1     1
```

**Risky solution**: This solution probably violates quite a few programming practices but still works as a hack. Assuming that you **do not** have nested `switch` statements then you can call a function like this in `otherwise` statement:

```
function allCases = getCases
st = dbstack('-completenames');
line = st(2).line;
fLines = importdata(st(2).file, sprintf('\n'));
switchLine = find(~cellfun(@isempty, ...
    regexp(fLines(1:line-1), '^\s*switch\s', 'once')), 1, 'last');
otherwLine = find(~cellfun(@isempty, ...
    regexp(fLines(1:line-1), '^\s*otherwise\s*$', 'once')), 1, 'last');
caseLines = fLines(switchLine+1:otherwLine-1);
casesStr = regexprep(caseLines(~cellfun(@isempty, ...
    regexp(caseLines, '^\s*case\s', 'once'))), '^\s*case\s*', '');
casesCells = cell(size(casesStr));
for iCases = 1:numel(casesCells);
    casesCells{iCases} = evalin('caller', casesStr{iCases});
end
allCases = [casesCells{:}];
end
```

Then if you run a code like this

```
a = 'a';
v = 'c';

switch a
    case {'b' v 1.2}
        %Multiple cases 
    case 2
        %number
    case ones(2)
        %matrix
    otherwise
        disp('Allowed cases are:');
        cellfun(@disp, getCases);
end
```

it prints out

```
Allowed cases are:
b
c
    1.2000
     2
     1     1
     1     1
```

Comment: This is horrifying.  But actually solves unsolvable problem presented.  I'm so conflicted.

Comment: Just so I understand, does your function import the calling function as text, search for lines with the words `switch` and `otherwise`, and then search between those lines for all instances of the word `case`, grab and evaluate the rest of the line, and then stick that into a cell? I don't yet know if I'm ready to go down that road until I've tried the other options, but +1 for hubris.

Comment: +1: it's horrible! awful! disgusting! revolting! terrifying! totally useless, unreadable, unmanageable,...but an awesome hack :)

Comment: You are a monster :). Your second solution is very elegant and does exactly what I want, however. Since I can't upvote that one separately, I will have to just accept the whole thing as my answer.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. I moved this solution to the beginning of the answer for some obvious reasons :-)

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44203-getcases-list-of-all-cases-in-a-switch) interesting :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis it's flattering to see that. Reading your first comment under this answer and finding out that you have used the idea in this submission feels weird. Would be nice if you mention this question in the description of file or just as a comment in the code.

Comment: oops...Sorry about that, it was absolutely my intention to give you some credit. I included it in the pending update :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Thanks, didn't mean to me personally, but as a background for the nice work you have done.

Answer (score 6):

To clarify, it sounds like what you are asking to do is something like the following:

```
value = 'z';
output = [];
switch value
    case 'a'
        output = 1.234;
    case 'b'
        output = 2.345;
    case 'c'
        output = 3.456;
    otherwise
        output = [];
        disp('Please use one the the following values:  a, b, c')
        %It would be nice to auto-populate that string wouldn't it?
end
```

That is not directly possible in Matlab (or any language I am aware of).

---

However, if you move from a switch/case statement to a more data-centric code design, it becomes easy.  For example, the above code can be re-written as:

```
%Setup (this can be preloaded and stored as persistent if too time consuming)
count = 1;
allvalues(count).name = 'a'; allvalues(count).value = 1.234; count = count+1;
allvalues(count).name = 'b'; allvalues(count).value = 2.345; count = count+1;
allvalues(count).name = 'c'; allvalues(count).value = 3.456; count = count+1;

%Lookup
value = 'z';  %Also try value = 'a'

maskMatch = strcmp({allvalues.name},value);
if any(maskMatch)
    output = allvalues(maskMatch).value;
else
    disp('Please use one of the following values:');
    disp({allvalues.name});
end
```

---

This is an example of using an array-of-structures to store data.  There are many ways to use Matlab data structures to store this kind of data, e.g. a Map or a cell array.  For a somewhat comprehensive list, see answers to this question:  [MATLAB Changing the name of a matrix with each iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15438464/931379)

Comment: This is only possible in specific cases: what if one `case` is a string, the next one a `function_handle`, the next one a `logical`, etc.?

Comment: Then I would replace the `.value` field with a `.functionHandle` field.  Then write a function (or anonymous, if it is short enough) for each case.  Instead of `output = data(mask).value;`, use `fn=data(mask).functionHandle; output = fn();`.

Comment: I was talking about the contents of `allvalues.name`. You are using `strcmp` to vectorially check the given string (`value`) against all supported strings (`allvalues.name`). This is a specific scenerario. What if instead of `value = 'z';`, the contents of `value` can be *any arbitrary class*? This method would lose any elegance it once had, especially compared to a `switch`. The generality of such a monster does *not* outweigh the burden of having to manage two identical lists...IMHO.

Comment: I misread your first comment.  Of course the right answer depends on the specifics of the problem; I think the original post was implementing a simple map from material name to parameter values.  If the case statement can be of different classes, then you could replace `strcmp({allvalues.name},value)` with `cellfun(@(x)isequal(value), {allvalues.name})`.

Comment: Well, you can have my vote :) It's somewhat reminiscent of the techniques shown in Loren Shure's blog post on [how to set default values for function argument](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/05/05/nice-way-to-set-function-defaults/).

Comment: "It would be nice to auto-populate that string wouldn't it?" That is exactly what I want, but for each case, I need to do something different. The optical properties function is a good example. For some materials, I have a lookup table that I load in and interpolate, some have an equation. But this is an interesting approach that I may be able to make work. I've just "discovered" structs, so it has special appeal to me at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no such mechanism. It may be possible in specific cases to pull off some vectorization tricks, but *generally* speaking, no.

And, if only from the perspective of (memory) efficiency, it would also be a bad idea to implement a `switch` like that (all the cases *may* be enormous matrices).

You can hack together such a mechanism:

```
% define all your cases in a cell
cases = {...
    'case1', 'case2', ...};

% and switch on these cases
switch [condition]
    case cases{1}
       % implement 'case1' 

   case cases{2}
       % implement 'case2' 

    ...

    otherwise
        char(cases) % contains all cases

end
```

Obviously, what you *gain* in generality, you *lose* in readability; the individual cases are now *not* at the same location as their corresponding code. Plus, the *order* of the content of `cases` is important, and [continues to list many drawbacks] ...

In short, it's not very pretty.

You could build a list yourself on-the-fly:

```
cases = {}; 

% FIRST CASE
if strcmp([condition], 'case1')
    % code for 'case1'

else % insert the case just checked for in the new list
    cases{end+1} = 'case1';
end

% SECOND CASE
if strcmp([condition], 'case2')
    % code for 'case2'

else % insert the case just checked for in the new list
    cases{end+1} = 'case2';
end

... % etc.
```

You're still essentially building 2 lists: one "anonymous" list in the `if`-statements, and one in the `cases` cell array. But each "case" is still an individual entity, and the case conditions are grouped per-case.

Of course, you *do* lose the power of a `switch`.

...and there's many more schemes. All comparable, and all with comparable drawbacks.

I'm afraid the best way to go here is to just live with it and manage two identical lists.