# Creating matrix names iteratively in MATLAB and performing operations

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 3-Dimensional matrix `K(i,j,l)`. I would like to create a new matrices from K, which would be a slice for each value of i. I also have to transpose the newly formed 2-D matrix.

```
for l=1:40  
    for j=1:15
       K1(l,j)=K(1,j,l);
       K2(l,j)=K(2,j,l);
.
.
.
       K35(l,j)=K(35,j,l);
    end;
end;
```

I want to create another loop where the names of new matrices are created within the loop.

i.e.;

```
K1(l,j)=K(1,j,l) (when i=1)
K2(l,j)=K(2,j,l) when i=2...
```

The problem that I faced is that I cannot seem to iteratively name of the matrices (K1,K2...K35) with in the loop and at the same time perform the dimension change operation. I tried `num2str`, `sprintf`, but they don't seem to work for some reason. If any of you have an idea, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any filename in your question. It's not very clear to me.

Comment: Sorry, there might have been a confusion. By file names I meant name of matrices K1, K2, K3 etc. My bad.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438464/matlab-changing-the-name-of-a-matrix-with-each-iteration/15439046#15439046

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to assign different names to your matrices. Can't you just store them in a cell like this:

```
K = cell(35, 1);
for ii=1:35
  K{ii} = squeeze(K_DEA(ii, :, :))';
end
```

Otherwise, if you really need to have different names, then do this:

```
K = cell(35, 1);
for ii=1:35
  eval(sprintf('K%d = squeeze(K_DEA(ii, :, :))'';', ii));
end
```

Comment: `squeeze` is needless.

Comment: I don't understand what user2923076 and jkshah are doing. 1. K(1,:,:) is a 3D array and it cannot be transposed in Matlab: they say jkshah's code works, I don't think so, it definitely doesn't on versions of Matlab earlier than R2010b. That's why you need squeeze. 2. Matlab strings need '', not "" like in jkshah's code. The latter produces errors, at least on versions of Matlab earlier than R2010b. Have Matlab new versions updated these features?

Comment: 1. As far as I know `K(1,:,:)` is **2D** matrix not **3D**. 2. Regarding syntax, I generally [compile online](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_matlab_online.php), though I haven't tested it on MatLab. As long as it works for OP, it should be fine.

Comment: Try K(1, :, :)' and it will return error: «??? Error using ==> ctranspose / Transpose on ND array is not defined». This happens also on the website that you suggested (which anyway compiles in Octave). So I am a bit puzzled.

Comment: Oops, sorry. You're true, my mistake. I might not have tested for 3D. For sake of simplicity I just tried 2D for testing, my bad. I have added `squeeze` to my solution. Now I am puzzled, how OP accepted it??!! He should have tested on his real data

Comment: Actually I thought «Hey! Did they change anything in Matlab lately?» :-)

Comment: I suppose not! bdw, your idea of storing in a cell is nice one. I am still puzzled what OP's doing! We may not get enough chance to test our solution, but he must have tested on his read data!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, following should solve your problem:

```
K1=squeeze(K(1,:,:))';
K2=squeeze(K(2,:,:))';
.
.
.
K35=squeeze(K(35,:,:))';
```

For looping over `i=1:35`

```
for i=1:35
  name = sprintf("K%d",i);
  A = squeeze(K(i,:,:))';
  eval([name ' = A']);
end
```

Or more concisely,

```
for i=1:35
  eval([sprintf("K%d = squeeze(K(i,:,:))'",i)]);
end
```

Comment: I am currently doing that, but I was wondering whether the changing values (1..35) can themselves be a part of a loop. That is, I need the matrix names to change within the loop. Since I have to do the same for quite a few matrices, it would be a bit cumbersome to do have too many lines.

Comment: @user2923076 Please note the addition of `squeeze` function to my solution.