# Storing each iteration of a loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 2d matrix (A=80,42), I am trying to split it into (80,1) 42 times and save it with a different name. i.e.

`M_n1`, `M_n2`, `M_n3`, … etc (representing the number of column)

I tried

```
for i= 1:42
    M_n(i)=A(:,i)
end
```

it didn't work

How can I do that without overwrite the result and save each iteration in a file (.txt) ?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438464/matlab-changing-the-name-of-a-matrix-with-each-iteration/. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval`

```
for ii = 1:size(A,2)
    eval( sprintf( 'M_n%d = A(:,%d);', ii, ii ) );
    % now you have M_n? var for you to process
end
```

However, the use of `eval` is [**not recommanded**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html#bs7kmd5), you might be better off using cell array

```
M_n = mat2cell( A, [size(A,1)], ones( 1, size(A,2) ) );
```

Now you have `M_n` a cell array with 42 cells one for each column of `A`.
You can access the `ii`-th column by `M_n{ii}`

Comment: Thanks all for your replies, Shai: If I want to print the 42 cells in 42 txt files (.txt), how can I do that ?

Comment: @Turki you can `dlmwrite` each of the `M_n{ii}` vectors.

Comment: I tried it inside the loop but with no luck, could you please write it in more details? Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Generally, doing if you consider doing this kind of things: don't.
It does not scale up well, and having them in one array is usually far more convenient.

As long as the results have the same shape, you can use a standard array, if not you can put each result in a cell array eg. :

```
results = cell(nTests,1)
result{1} = runTest(inputs{1})
```

or even

```
results = cellfun(@runTest,inputs,'UniformOutput',false); % where inputs is a cell array
```

And so on.

If you do want to write the numbers to a file at each iteration, you could do it without the names with `csvwrite` or the like (since you're only talking about 80 numbers a time).

Another option is using `matfile`, which lets you write directly to a variable in a .mat file. Consult `help matfile` for the specifics.

Comment: Thank you for your help, appreciated