# Variable name the same as data in array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, variables

I have data which is in a cell array. I want each row in the cell array to be assigned a variable name which is the same as what is there in the first column of that row. Can I have this in a loop?

```
'P' 'El'    'Ge'    'R' 'M'  'RANGE'
'A' 'El'    'Ge'    'T' 'M'  'RANGE' 
'B' 'El'    'Ge'    'K' 'M'  'RANGE' 
'D' 'El'    'Ge'    'M' 'NM' 'RANGE'
```

For example I want first row of this array to have a variable name of P, the second row a variable name of A, the third row a variable name of B and so on.

Comment: That would require a lot of `assignin` (_or even worse_ `eval`). It is recommended to [Generate Field Names from Variables](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html), or use a cell array but that's already what you've got.

Comment: Everytime someone use `eval`, God is killing a kitten. No jokking, @Hoki is totally right

Comment: Is there any other way i can do this.I have whatever in the first column as a part of my dropdown menu in my GUI.So i was wondering if i could have variables with the same name.

Comment: would you be happy with one central variable containing a field for each of your line, like `data.P`, `data.A`, `data.B` ... ans so on ?

Comment: yes that would do.Thanks

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior - That is currently our MATLAB Chat Room Creedence.  Thank you for the idea lol.  Come visit us whenever you have time and say hi! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave

Comment: Can somebody please explain to me why doing this would be a good thing?

Comment: Can you also use associative arrays?  Use a `containers.Map` and use the first column as keys and the entire rest of a row as the values.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15438464/931379. I think the more general question here is "how should I store named data in Matlab".

Comment: @Hoki could you please explain me on how do i go about creating data.p data.A data.B?Thanks

Comment: Yes, I guess after a full day of chit-chat, someone could actually just put in some reasonable sample code here. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
dataCell = {...
    'P' 'El'    'Ge'    'R' 'M'  'RANGE'; ...
    'A' 'El'    'Ge'    'T' 'M'  'RANGE'; ... 
    'B' 'El'    'Ge'    'K' 'M'  'RANGE'; ...
    'D' 'El'    'Ge'    'M' 'NM' 'RANGE'};
```

Use a loop looks like this:

```
for ix = 1:size(dataCell ,1)
    curFieldName = dataCell{ix, 1};
    curData = dataCell(ix, 2:end);  %You can put other data here
    data.(curFieldName) = curData;  %Note the ".()' notation
end
```

This leverages a weird syntax feature in Matlab, which is used to reference a field whose name is stored in a variable. Example below

```
%If you know the name of a field when you are writing the code, 
%use this syntax
someStructure.field1 = 1;

%If you want the name of the filed to be generated dynamically, when 
%the code is executed, use this syntax (note parenthesis). 
theFieldNameInAVariable = 'field1';
someStructure.(theFieldNameInAVariable ) = 1
```

That results in the structure `data`, which looks like this:

```
>> data
data = 
    P: {'El'  'Ge'  'R'  'M'  'RANGE'}
    A: {'El'  'Ge'  'T'  'M'  'RANGE'}
    B: {'El'  'Ge'  'K'  'M'  'RANGE'}
    D: {'El'  'Ge'  'M'  'NM'  'RANGE'}
```

This is the "**Use a structure**" option as described here: stackoverflow.com/q/15438464/931379. There are at least four good options in the top answers to that question (plus a description of how to do this with variable names.)

Bottom line, there are a lot of ways to store named data in Matlab. Using a structure, like this, is a pretty decent one for many purposes.